# How to detect when an item is removed from an Primeng autocomplete | Angular 6

Tags: angular, user-interface, autocomplete, primeng, angular-material-6

I am using a dynamic primeng autocomplete to let user select multiple items, but i am stuck on how to detect when user pressed the `x` to remove the item from the list. i know i can use the `[(ngModel)]` to detect value change, but my question is:
 **Is there a way like a callback function to detect the removed item when the `x` is pressed** ?

**as defined:**

```
<p-autoComplete
            #autoCompleteObject
            [(ngModel)]="value" [suggestions]="filteredOptions"
            (completeMethod)="filterObjects($event)"
            [multiple]="true"
            [dropdown]="false"
            (onSelect)="emitData()"
            (onUnselect)="emitData()"
            placeholder="{{ label | i18n}}"
    >
        <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <div class="selected-item">
                <span >{{item[labelProperty]}}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
            <div class="flex ">
                <span >{{item[labelProperty] | i18n}}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>

    </p-autoComplete>
```

**as used**

```
 <my-autocomplete-multiple [(ngModel)]="entryItems" label='type_here' [options]=allItems
                                          ngDefaultControl></my-autocomplete-multiple>
```

As the photo below, i circled the `x` with red color
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete), the `onUnselect()` callback method is invoked when a selected value is removed. The `$event` parameter is the unselected value in multiple mode.

Instead of binding `emitData()` to both the `onSelect()` and `onUnselect()` methods, I recommend using a separate method for each, like so:

```
(onSelect)="emitAddData($event)"
(onUnselect)="emitRemoveData($event)"
```

Then the one that's bound to `onUnselect()` can handle whatever you need to do when an item is removed.